# XSLT Filter result using XSLT array

Tags: xpath, xslt-1.0, transformation, xslt

I am a beginner in XSLT.

Below is source XML which i receive. `Request` tag constains the `FlightId` which is being used to filter the `Result` tag.

**Source XML:**

```
<Response>
    <Request>
        <RequestedFlights>
            <FlightId>2121</FlightId>
            <FlightId>2584</FlightId>
        </RequestedFlights>
    </Request>
    <Result>
        <Flights>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>2</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>1121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>3</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>4</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>5</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>6</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>7</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2023</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
        </Flights>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:variable name="ReqFlights" select="//Request/RequestedFlights/FlightId" />
    <xsl:variable name="FilterFlights" select="//Result/Flights/Flight[Segments/Segment/FlightNumber=$ReqFlights]"/>

    <xsl:template match="Response">
        <FilterResult>
            <ResultCount>
                <xsl:value-of select="count($FilterFlights)"/>
            </ResultCount>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$FilterFlights"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </FilterResult>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I received below output using above XSLT.

**Output:**

```
<FilterResult>
    <ResultCount>3</ResultCount>
    <Response>
        <Flight>
            <Segments>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>1</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>2</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>1121</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
            </Segments>
        </Flight>
            <Flight>
            <Segments>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>3</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>4</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
            </Segments>
        </Flight>
            <Flight>
            <Segments>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>5</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>6</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>7</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2023</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
            </Segments>
        </Flight>
    </Response>
</FilterResult>
```

I would like to receive below output.

**Expected Output:**

```
<FilterResult>
    <ResultCount>1</ResultCount>
    <Response>
        <Flight>
            <Segments>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>3</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
                <Segment>
                    <Id>4</Id>
                    <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                </Segment>
            </Segments>
        </Flight>
    </Response>
</FilterResult>
```

Please help me. How should i use the array to filter the response and get expected output.
Thanks.

Comment: Nicely constructed question. +1.

Comment: Why is ResultCount 1 when there are two FlightNumbers?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin ResultCount 1 because the "FilterFlights" variable should have only one `Flight` node.

Comment: So what is the rule here? Does a Flight have to contain **all** the FlightId's in order for it to be output?

Comment: What is the minimum and maximum number of FlightId s? Is it unbounded?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Here rule is to filter the `Flight` node which contains the all requested `FlightNumber`. If you look at first `Flight` node it has `2121` flight number but doesn't have `2584` flight number. While the 2nd `Flight` node has both the flight number. Hope this make sense.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Yes it is unbounded.

Comment: What about if a flight contained all of the FlightIds, but it also contained flightnumbers which were not in the RequestedFlights? Would that Flight still be output?

Comment: No it should have exactly those `FlightId` as `FlightNumber`

Comment: I see. Would you be able to extend the sample documents to illustrate that last point?

Comment: Also, if a Flight has EXACTLY the FlightNumbers as Requested FlightIds, are they guarenteed to be in the same order? (Compareing Flights to RequestedFlights) Or is there no ordering relationship?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Edited the question. Yes there will be in the same order. But if we get the solution independent of order then it would be great else no prob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/Result/*/Flight
            [count(*/*)=count(/*/Request/*/FlightId)
           and
             not(*/*/FlightNumber[not(. = /*/Request/*/FlightId)])
            ]
```

**Here is the complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vHits" select=
     "/*/Result/*/Flight
                  [count(*/*)=count(/*/Request/*/FlightId)
                 and
                   not(*/*/FlightNumber[not(. = /*/Request/*/FlightId)])
                   ]"/>
    <FilterResult>
    <ResultCount><xsl:value-of select="count($vHits)"/></ResultCount>
    <Response>
     <xsl:copy-of select="$vHits"/>
    </Response>
  </FilterResult>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Response>
    <Request>
        <RequestedFlights>
            <FlightId>2121</FlightId>
            <FlightId>2584</FlightId>
        </RequestedFlights>
    </Request>
    <Result>
        <Flights>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>1</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>2</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>1121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>3</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>4</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
            <Flight>
                <Segments>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>5</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>6</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                    <Segment>
                        <Id>7</Id>
                        <FlightNumber>2023</FlightNumber>
                    </Segment>
                </Segments>
            </Flight>
        </Flights>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<FilterResult>
   <ResultCount>1</ResultCount>
   <Response>
      <Flight>
         <Segments>
            <Segment>
               <Id>3</Id>
               <FlightNumber>2121</FlightNumber>
            </Segment>
            <Segment>
               <Id>4</Id>
               <FlightNumber>2584</FlightNumber>
            </Segment>
         </Segments>
      </Flight>
   </Response>
</FilterResult>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of the **[double negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation)** law.

Comment: Thanks. For the given source XML your solution works. But when i need to apply same law for different structured XML. Should i create new Question or edit this?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani, It is better for everybody if you create a new question -- otherwise you'll destroy the first question, or make it less readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />  

<xsl:variable name="requested"
  select="/Response/Request/RequestedFlights/FlightId/text()" />

<xsl:template name="flights-as-string">
  <xsl:param name="Id" />
  <xsl:for-each select="$Id">
    <xsl:sort select="." />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[',.,']')" />
  </xsl:for-each>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="requested-str-nodeset">
  <xsl:call-template name="flights-as-string">
    <xsl:with-param name="Id" select="$requested" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>  
<xsl:variable name="requested-str" select="exsl:node-set($requested-str-nodeset)/text()" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="flight-output">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Result/Flights/Flight" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <FilterResult>
    <ResultCount><xsl:value-of select="
      count( exsl:node-set($flight-output)/Flight)" /></ResultCount>
    <Response>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$flight-output" />
    </Response>
  </FilterResult>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Flight">
  <xsl:variable name="actual-str">
    <xsl:call-template name="flights-as-string">
      <xsl:with-param name="Id" select="Segments/Segment/FlightNumber/text()" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>  
  <xsl:if test="$requested-str = exsl:node-set($actual-str)/text()">
      <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```