# Filter Org Chart Results - varying depth of hierarchy

Tags: xml, xslt, filter, organizational-chart

I'm hoping you can point me in the right direction with this issue. I'm trying to get a filtered result of our org chart to show each department. A sample of the source xml is below. I can restructure the xml source if there is a better way to do it based on my requirements.

**Source XML:**

```
<OrgTree>
    <employee ID="1">
        <Name>John</Name>
        <Department>President's Office</Department>
        <employee ID="2">
            <Name>Ron</Name>
            <Department>President's Office</Department>
            <employee ID="3">
                <Name>Don</Name>
                <Department>CEO</Department>
            </employee>
        </employee>
        <employee ID="4">
            <Name>Mike</Name>
            <Department>Finance</Department>
            <employee ID="5">
                <Name>Mark</Name>
                <Department>Accounting</Department>
                <employee ID="6">
                    <Name>Marni</Name>
                    <Department>Accounting</Department>
                </employee>
            </employee>
            <employee ID="7">
                <Name>Mindy</Name>
                <Department>Investments</Department>
            </employee>
        </employee>
    </employee>
</OrgTree>
```

I would like to get the output in 2 different forms.

1. Filter by a department and get all nodes from that department and child departments (filter by finance tree).

**Output 1:**

```
<OrgTree>
    <employee ID="4">
        <Name>Mike</Name>
        <Department>Finance</Department>
        <employee ID="5">
        <Name>Mark</Name>
            <Department>Accounting</Department>
            <employee ID="6">
                <Name>Marni</Name>
                <Department>Accounting</Department>
            </employee>
        </employee>
        <employee ID="7">
        <Name>Mindy</Name>
        <Department>Investments</Department>
        </employee>
    </employee>
</OrgTree>
```

2. Filter the output by a specific department and get just nodes in that department

**Output 2:**

```
<OrgTree>
<employee ID="5">
    <Name>Mark</Name>
    <Department>Accounting</Department>
    <employee ID="6">
        <Name>Marni</Name>
        <Department>Accounting</Department>
    </employee>
</employee>
</OrgTree>
```

I found a couple posts on filtering like this one [XSLT Filter result using XSLT array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491404/xslt-filter-result-using-xslt-array) but my xml structure is different enough that I'm not having any luck getting that approach to work.

I'm in SharePoint so the xsl to filter by department-only I'm trying is below, but I get no results since there is only one parent row in the xml. I've played with a number of different ways of doing the filter in the rowview template which kind of work, but I would like to just pass filtered results to the rowview template without having to iterate through all the nodes there. I'm at a loss with how to do this given the varying depth of child nodes.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$Rows[Department = 'CFO']">
     <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowview"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Any help, guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: you've included next to no code. Perhaps try writing some more.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback copyright nightmare.. I could have pasted the 20 variations of for each and choose statements I've tried. But they don't work the way I need them to. As I said I don't know how to iterate through an unknown depth of nodes. And the code I use in the dvt_1.rowview to draw the org chart out for each staff member is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: If the code is that sensitive, perhaps it's a question you can't ask on a public forum. Try cutting the problem down into smaller chunks and sung of you can figure out the solution from there.

Answer (score 1):

You would probably start off by using the identity template, which can use used to copy nodes without changes

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You would then have a template for **employee** elements where you could decide whether you were going to copy them or not. If they had a department matching the one you wanted, or had an ancestor with one, then you would copy it. Otherwise you would continue processing at the child **employee** elements

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="ancestor-or-self::employee[Department=$dept]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

(Where **$dept** is a parameter containing the department name you wish to filter)

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:param name="dept" select="'Finance'"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="employee">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="ancestor-or-self::employee[Department=$dept]">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="employee"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should give you "Output 1". For "Output 2", just change the condition to this

```
<xsl:when test="self::employee[Department=$dept]">
```

Or better still, to just this

```
<xsl:when test="Department=$dept">
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I wasn't familiar with the identity template approach.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I wasn't familiar enough with the identity template approach. This does give me the output I'm looking for, but I'm realizing maybe by the way I phased the question that I'm not looking for an xml output, but a way to address the output of the filter by sending it to the "rowview" template. Can I use do that?

Comment: Hmm... Possibly you need to ask a whole new question, I think!